# How to do look up variable by ID when there are two ID columns and line by line?

Tags: r, statistics

I have a dataset that matches people together and then calculates a score (D1N and D2N) for the two people based on the absolute difference between the two people's scores (PS1 and PS2 as calculated in SD) and their current D scores (D1 and D2). I have the dataset set up so that the first time a person makes an appearance in a match between people (either as P1 OR P2) their D score is 1 by default (I have a time variable in the dataset to do this). Below is an example of a smaller and simpler dataset to play around with.

```
  dataset <- structure(list(Time = 1:5, P1 = c(1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 5L), P2 = c(2L, 
             2L, 5L, 1L, 4L), PS1 = c(1, -0.3, -0.3, 2.5, 0.5), PS2 = c(2.5, 
                2.5, 0.5, 1, -1), SD = c(1.5, 2.8, 0.8, 1.5, 1.5), D1 = c(1L, 
                 1L, NA, NA, NA), D2 = c(1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L), D1N = c(1.224744871, 
                    NA, NA, NA, NA), D2N = c(1.224744871, NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("Time", 
           "P1", "P2", "PS1", "PS2", "SD", "D1", "D2", "D1N", "D2N"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                               -5L))
```

What I am trying to do is calculate DN1 and DN2 line by line so that if D1 and D2 aren't 1 then the code looks up the person's id (P1 and P2) to get their previous D score. So for instance in the second line of the dataset I want D2 to be 1.224745 since that is their most recent D score. Then DN2 for that line would calculate at 2.049 and then that would be the number put in D1 for Time 4. The exact calculations aren't really important here I am just trying to give a more simple example since the main question is how to get the numbers to fill in in later rows based on id when the id is across 2 columns.

I know there's a little line by line code that would look something like this:

```
  for (row in 1:nrow(dataset)){ 
#code here that will pull previous D value based on ID across columns if D is not 1
dataset$D1N <- dataset$D1*sqrt(dataset$SD)  
dataset$D2N <- dataset$D2*sqrt(dataset$SD)  
    }
```

but I don't know how to get the ID lookup across two columns.

To be clear P1 and P2 are just two columns to match people together but the IDs in both columns are still unique IDs (if someone is 5 in the P1 column that is the same person as the person who is 5 in the P2 column).

What would be a way to go about doing this? Thanks for the help!

Comment: In your example, should `D2N` for the second row be `1.224745*sqrt(2.8) = 2.049` ? I don't understand how `1.93649` would be calculated.

Comment: Sorry I had more detail on how the calculations are made but I cut those details out to try and make the main point of the question more the focus and that probably made some of the calculations confusing. I think that number you have is right but the main issue is I still have no idea how to match ID across two columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a potential solution that works by creating a separate lookup table for the player ID that is sorted in descending time

```
library(reshape2)

#create melted table to lookup player ID
players<-melt(dataset[,1:3], id.vars="Time", value.name = "player_id")
players<-players[order(players$Time, decreasing = TRUE),]
players$variable<-gsub("P", "",players$variable)
players$lookup_col<-paste0("D", players$variable, "N")

players

#   Time variable player_id lookup_col
#5     5        1         5        D1N
#10    5        2         4        D2N
#4     4        1         2        D1N
#9     4        2         1        D2N
#3     3        1         3        D1N
#8     3        2         5        D2N
#2     2        1         3        D1N
#7     2        2         2        D2N
#1     1        1         1        D1N
#6     1        2         2        D2N
```

Then you can loop through your dataset, filling in the NA's and calculating D1N and D2N

```
for (row in 2:nrow(dataset)){ 
  p1<-dataset[row,"P1"]
  p2<-dataset[row,"P2"]
  D1<-dataset[row,"D1"]
  D2<-dataset[row,"D2"]

  #if D1 or D2 is blank, lookup the last game by that ID in the "players" dataframe
  #and retrieve that row from the dataset

    if(is.na(D1)) {
    pl_row<-players[which(players$Time<row & players$player_id==p1)[1],]
    D1<-dataset[pl_row$Time, pl_row$lookup_col] 
    dataset[row, "D1"]<-D1
    }

    if(is.na(D2)) {
    pl_row<-players[which(players$Time<row & players$player_id==p2)[1],]
    D2<-dataset[pl_row$Time, pl_row$lookup_col]
    dataset[row, "D2"]<-D2
    }

  dataset[row, "D1N"] <- D1*sqrt(dataset[row, "SD"])  
  dataset[row, "D2N"] <- D2*sqrt(dataset[row, "SD"])  
}

dataset

#  Time P1 P2  PS1  PS2  SD        D1       D2      D1N       D2N
# 1    1  1  2  1.0  2.5 1.5 1.0000000 1.000000 1.224745 1.2247449
# 2    2  3  2 -0.3  2.5 2.8 1.0000000 1.224745 1.673320 2.0493902
# 3    3  3  5 -0.3  0.5 0.8 1.6733201 1.000000 1.496663 0.8944272
# 4    4  2  1  2.5  1.0 1.5 2.0493902 1.224745 2.509980 1.5000000
# 5    5  5  4  0.5 -1.0 1.5 0.8944272 1.000000 1.095445 1.2247449
```

Comment: That works thank you sooooo much! This was a wonderful solution I really appreciate all the help! Thanks again and sorry for the trouble!